# change CSS where font-weight:800

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering if there was a way to change CSS on mass where "font-weight: 800" and replace it with 700.

I have a work website that i go to and they've changed all their font-weight from 'bold' to 800 and it makes it look ugly. Was hoping to use Tampermonkey to return it to normal with jquery or javascript.

There are lots of classes and IDs where it has been changed, looks like someone went through the .css file and went find 'bold' replaceWith '800'

Comment: Will Find and Replace work?

Comment: @George How can we do a find and replace on the css of an already rendered page? something like document.styleSheets[1].text ?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a website you were working on. I know some browsers let you specify user stylesheets that override website styles, but I don't know what browsers support it anymore (I know a bunch dropped it for no reason a while ago). Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can target the tag whose `font-weight` has been changed to `800` and then override that using `font-weight: bold !important`. For example, if the `p` tag's font-weight has been changed to `800` like this:

```
p {
     font-weight: 800;
}
```

You can override it by placing this at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
p {
     font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

You can do the same for the heading tags etc.

Another solution would be to open your stylesheet inside a code editor and simply find and replace all the instances of `font-weight: 800px` with `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: thanks but the problem was finding all the different rules where font-weight was set to 800 in the first place. It turns out jQuery is the easiest for this, `$('*').each(function(e,i){if($(e).css('font-weight') == '800') // do something })`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this, you will need to use on page load or something rather than the button click like in the fiddle demo but other than that you shouldnt have any problems.

**EDIT** edited the code after it was brought to my attention i messed up

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    $("*").each(function(){
        var fontWeight = $(this).css("font-weight");       
        if(fontWeight == "800"){
            $(this).css("font-weight", "100");
        }
    });   
});
```

to make this work for your needs just change the 100 to 700 i have it at that to show the change.

Here is the updated demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/nws54e0g/4/)

Comment: How does this answer the question? Your code changes all elements on the page to bold and then immediately removes the bold style from all elements.

Comment: i used the `font-weight`s i did to show the change as it was barely visible on jsfiddle, he could very easily modify it by changing 2 words..

Comment: Maybe you just didn't understand the question. See here http://jsfiddle.net/nws54e0g/1/ notice how the "normal" text is changed to bold as well? Your code changes all elements, not just the 800 weight ones.

Comment: i did mess up my bad i fixed it :)